# The closure of the set of rationals linear combinations is a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real normed space, $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ a countable subset of $X$ and define $Y$ as the set of all linear combinations of elements of $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with rational coefficients.

I want to prove $\overline{Y}$ is a subspace of $X$. I already proved that $\overline{Y}$ is closed under finite sum.

Now let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\overline{Y}$. We need to show $rx\in\overline{Y}$.

This is what I've tried. Let $(y_n)\subseteq Y$ a sequence that converges to $x$. So, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}q_k^{(n)}x_k$$where $q_k^{(n)}$ is rational and all but finitely many are zero. I'd like to show a sequence in $Y$ that converges to $rx$, but I haven't been able to do it yet. For every $k$ and $n$ we can take a new sequence $(p_{k,m}^{(n)})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $rq_{k}^{(n)}$, but how to define a sequence with these new coefficients that converges to $rx$? I think I'm messing it with the indexes.

Would anyone give me a hint?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first with rational $r$. For irrational $r$ use a diagonal subsequence

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/685265)

Comment: I think it provides quite a big hint, as requested by the author.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Also, I didn't need clarification. I just pointed out that if you solve *first* for rational $r$'s, and *then* you confront the other $r$'s, it becomes easier than handling approximations for every coefficient, which I understand can get you lost. Maybe I have a general issue: what to do when a user asks for hints? Should I make a comment? There are tens of questions marked as unanswered just because the answer was in the comments

Comment: Thank you both. It did help. Though I noticed also that the way I wrote wasn't the best. It was better to approximate using $\epsilon 's$. But thank you.